# Removing item from shopping cart, decrease and increase

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am building an simple shop page, and I want to remove dhe items from the shopping cart,or decrease and increase. But I can't find the solution. I can add them in shopping cart but I can't remove the items the error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inCart' of undefined
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous>
(anonymous) 
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inCart' of undefined
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous>
(anonymous)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inCart' of undefined
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous> anybody please.
```

```js
let carts = document.querySelectorAll('.add-cart');

let products = [

{
    name: 'TCX ADVANCED PRO 1',
    tag: 'bike_giant5',
    price:4400,
    inCart: 0
},
{
    name: 'REVOLT ADVANCED 0',
    tag: 'bike_giant6',
    price:3650,
    inCart: 0
},

{
    name: 'REVOLT ADVANCED 1',
    tag: 'bike_giant7',
    price:2600,
    inCart: 0
},
{
    name: 'REVOLT E+ PRO',
    tag: 'bike_giant8',
    price:4200,
    inCart: 0
},
{
    name: 'EXPLORE E+ 4 GTS',
    tag: 'bike_giant9',
    price:2500,
    inCart: 0
},
{
    name: 'TCX ADVANCED',
    tag: 'bike_giant10',
    price:2550,
    inCart: 0
}


];

for(let i=0; i< carts.length; i++) {
    carts[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        cartNumbers(products[i]);
        totalCost(products[i]);
    });
}

function onLoadCartNumbers() {
    let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');
    if( productNumbers ) {
        document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = productNumbers;
    }
}

function cartNumbers(product, action) {
    let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');
    productNumbers = parseInt(productNumbers);

    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);

    if( action ) {
        localStorage.setItem("cartNumbers", productNumbers - 1);
        document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = productNumbers - 1;
        console.log("action running");
    } else if( productNumbers ) {
        localStorage.setItem("cartNumbers", productNumbers + 1);
        document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = productNumbers + 1;
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("cartNumbers", 1);
        document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = 1;
    }
    setItems(product);
}

function setItems(product) {
    let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');
    productNumbers = parseInt(productNumbers);
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);

    if(cartItems != null) {
        let currentProduct = product.tag;
    
        if( cartItems[currentProduct] == undefined ) {
            cartItems = {
                ...cartItems,
                [currentProduct]: product
            }
        } 
        cartItems[currentProduct].inCart += 1;

    } else {
        product.inCart = 1;
        cartItems = { 
            [product.tag]: product
        };
    }

    localStorage.setItem('productsInCart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
}

function totalCost( product, action ) {
    let cart = localStorage.getItem("totalCost");

    if( action) {
        cart = parseInt(cart);

        localStorage.setItem("totalCost", cart - product.price);
    } else if(cart != null) {
        
        cart = parseInt(cart);
        localStorage.setItem("totalCost", cart + product.price);
    
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("totalCost", product.price);
    }
}

function displayCart() {
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);

    let cart = localStorage.getItem("totalCost");
    cart = parseInt(cart);

    let productContainer = document.querySelector('.products');
    
    if( cartItems && productContainer ) {
        productContainer.innerHTML = '';
        Object.values(cartItems).map( (item, index) => {
            productContainer.innerHTML += 
            `<div class="product"><ion-icon name="close-circle"></ion-icon><img src="./images/bike/${item.tag}.jpg" />
                <span class="sm-hide">${item.name}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="price sm-hide">$${item.price},00</div>
            <div class="quantity">
                <ion-icon class="decrease " name="arrow-dropleft-circle"></ion-icon>
                    <span>${item.inCart}</span>
                <ion-icon class="increase" name="arrow-dropright-circle"></ion-icon>   
            </div>
            <div class="total">$${item.inCart * item.price},00</div>`;
        });

        productContainer.innerHTML += `
            <div class="basketTotalContainer">
                <h4 class="basketTotalTitle">Basket Total</h4>
                <h4 class="basketTotal">$${cart},00</h4>
            </div>`

        deleteButtons();
        manageQuantity();
    }
}

function manageQuantity() {
    let decreaseButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.decrease');
    let increaseButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.increase');
    let currentQuantity = 0;
    let currentProduct = '';
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);

    for(let i=0; i < increaseButtons.length; i++) {
        decreaseButtons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log(cartItems);
            currentQuantity = decreaseButtons[i].parentElement.querySelector('span').textContent;
            console.log(currentQuantity);
            currentProduct = decreaseButtons[i].parentElement.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.querySelector('span').textContent.toLocaleLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'').trim();
            console.log(currentProduct);

            if( cartItems[currentProduct].inCart > 1 ) {
                cartItems[currentProduct].inCart -= 1;
                cartNumbers(cartItems[currentProduct], "decrease");
                totalCost(cartItems[currentProduct], "decrease");
                localStorage.setItem('productsInCart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
                displayCart();
            }
        });

        increaseButtons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log(cartItems);
            currentQuantity = increaseButtons[i].parentElement.querySelector('span').textContent;
            console.log(currentQuantity);
            currentProduct = increaseButtons[i].parentElement.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.querySelector('span').textContent.toLocaleLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'').trim();
            console.log(currentProduct);

            cartItems[currentProduct].inCart += 1;
            cartNumbers(cartItems[currentProduct]);
            totalCost(cartItems[currentProduct]);
            localStorage.setItem('productsInCart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
            displayCart();
        });
    }
}

function deleteButtons() {
    let deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.product ion-icon');
    let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');
    let cartCost = localStorage.getItem("totalCost");
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
    let productName;
    console.log(cartItems);

    for(let i=0; i < deleteButtons.length; i++) {
        deleteButtons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
            productName = deleteButtons[i].parentElement.textContent.toLocaleLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'').trim();
           
            localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', productNumbers - cartItems[productName].inCart);
            localStorage.setItem('totalCost', cartCost - ( cartItems[productName].price * cartItems[productName].inCart));

            delete cartItems[productName];
            localStorage.setItem('productsInCart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));

            displayCart();
            onLoadCartNumbers();
        })
    }
}

onLoadCartNumbers();
displayCart();
```

```html
<li><a href="cart.html"><ion-icon name="basket"></ion-icon>Cart<span>0</span></a></li>

<div class="grid-container">
<div class="item1"><div class="overlay">TCX ADVANCED PRO 1<br>
    4,400$<br><button class="add-cart">Click</button></div></div>
<div class="item2"><div class="overlay">REVOLT ADVANCED 0<br>
    3,650$<br><button class="add-cart">Click</button></div></div>
<div class="item3"><div class="overlay">REVOLT ADVANCED 1<br>
    2,600$<br><button class="add-cart">Click</button></div></div>  
<div class="item4"><div class="overlay">REVOLT E+ PRO<br>
    4,200$<br><button class="add-cart">Click</button></div></div>
<div class="item5"><div class="overlay">EXPLORE E+ 4 GTS<br>
    2,500$<br><button class="add-cart">Click</button></div></div>
<div class="item6"><div class="overlay">TCX ADVANCED<br>
    2,550$<br><button class="add-cart">Click</button></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the space from product name
let products = [

{
name: 'TCX-ADVANCED-PRO-1',
tag: 'bike_giant5',
price:4400,
inCart: 0
},